# Mobinuke not loading CSS files

Tags: mobile, dotnetnuke

I'm working on a mobile project for a site based originially off DNN 4.8.2. Since mobinuke 2 is no longer available for purchase I've had to upgrade the site to 5.4.5 in order to work with mobinuke 3. We completed the mobile skin only to realize that DNN 5 has some major performance problems. As a result we upgraded the whole site up to 6.1.2 (which should still be compatible with mobinuke 3).

The problem that we're having now is that mobinuke is no longer loading any of the CSS files. Not the CSS file in the mobinuke skin folder, nor any of the module.css files. Obviously I can work around this and manually load all the CSS files that I need. But as the module should be working and loading these files, I'm curious to know if anyone else has had this problem and if they have found any solutions besides manually loading the CSS files.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds interesting, if you are migrated correctly, you can try installing other skin and module and check if it is working or not that will help to know if there is problem with the module or site instance